# Aircraft Wing Analysis - Elliptical Pressure Distribution

Tags: integration, fluid-dynamics, elliptic-equations, elliptic-integrals, statics

I'm having great difficulty with generating the shear and bending moment diagrams for a wingspan. I am using the elliptical pressure distribution equation; however, this problem doesn't consider a density or velocity. [image: Integrated Lift Expression] I have a lift of $50000 N$, so I have found $P_0$ to be 4244. Now I have segmented my aircraft span into $0.05m$ segments from $-7.5$ to $7.5$. I am calling this $dy$ (0,0.05, 0.1 etc...). I can then use my $$p(y) = p_0\cdot\sqrt{1-(4y^2/b^2)}$$ [image: eqn] to find the pressure at all $dy$ points of the span. This plot looks fine and is elliptical. [image: Plot]

Now the area under this curve should be the shear force. So, my thinking is to integrate the $P(y)$ equation over area. I believe this will just become the following [image: Eqn]

However here my area is actually my $dA=dy*c$ ($c$ = constant chord length across span of 2m) AND for $y$ I'm using my segmented $dy$ values, which feels wrong as I'm actually integrating over $dA$ and the [image: Function] is actually using 'A' and 'y' - not the discretised values, although I'm not sure that 100% matters? Anyway, this gives a decent looking graph I think, for shear vs span [image: here] - Although I'm not sure it is right. Finally, I cannot work out the bending moment calculations and cannot get a decent looking graph. Have been going in circles online looking for methods but can't seem to remember the key steps of numerical integration for these kinds of problems. Any help on both the shear and bending moment diagrams would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me insane!!

Edit: If I were to integrate over dy [Integrating over dy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpkho.png)which looks exactly like the pressure graph and not shear force.

EXCEL SNIPPET: [Net Pressure Force (Pressure(y)/dA) vs Span](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i17V7.png)

Comment: You have an expression for shear force that has both $A$ and $y$ in it, but then you show a graph of shear vs. span that has only one axis for the input -- how does it relate to $A$ and $y$? Also, given how you said shear force should equal the area under the previous curve, how does it make any sense for shear force to be negative on part of the graph?

Comment: It's related through dA=dy*c, although this doesn't look correct. Think I'm confused as a whole how to get from my p(y) to V(y) and M(y)

Comment: This is one way learning MathJax (https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) would help you communicate your question better, because you could write the equation with that substitution and not just the picture of the equation you got from software. But this also reminds me that $A$ seems to have come from nowhere--why are you integrating a function over $dA$ to find an area? Usually the symbol $A$ **is** area.

Comment: So I have total area of the wing (A=7.5m span x 2m chord=15m^2). Now y is the distance along the span. I have discretised this span into 0.05m segments, these are dy. Therefore each segment will have an area dA which is = dA=dy*c. Apologies if I'm not making sense. Wouldn't I be integrating my pressure function over this area to get V(y)?

Comment: Have added an edit. Although still confused :/

Comment: Is your goal to find the area under the curve of the second screenshot--the one with $y$ and $\Gamma$? If that's the case, then I think you can evaluate $\int_{-b/2}^{b/2} \Gamma(y)dy$. In your case, that would be $4244\int_{-7.5}^{7.5} \sqrt{1-\frac{(2y)^2}{b^2}}dy$. If $b$ is a constant, you should be able to evaluate the integral using a trig substitution.

Comment: Hey sorry for the confusion. I'm under the impression that through integrating the net pressure forces on each panel, I can get a shear force distribution in terms of y, however I keep going in circles with the shear graph and it always has the same shape as the pressure graph but with a different scale - which I know is wrong. Please see the bottom of the post for a snippet of the excel. THanks

Comment: You haven't given any information from which we can see how to relate the area of the wing to its length. You've only given information about pressure. If you're also supposed to account for area, the explicit formula should occur *before* you use $A$ and everything that varies with $A$ in the integral needs to be expressed as a function of $A$. Basically, you need a very clear model of exactly what it is you're doing and why, not just "now I find the area under this curve for unstated reasons."